# How to configure Eslint indent rules for 3 space?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint

I like to use my Javascript file indentation to 3 spaces. But Eslint doesn't like this way and it gives me some indentation warning.
How should I fix it?

And when we work with team other team members maybe configure their editor and formatter differently. In this case how should I configure Eslint?
And also what if I don't want Eslit to give me any indentation error.

```
error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 3

warning  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 3 spaces
warning  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6 spaces
warning  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6 spaces
warning  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 3 spaces
```

Clarification from comments:

*"I don't use prettier"*

Comment: `{"indent": ["error", 3]}` should work -> https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent

Comment: ESlint is not used for formatting, this is the job of Prettier. Set the [tabWidth](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) to 3.

Comment: @kissu, if you use both `eslint` and `prettier`, you need to align both rules.

Comment: @ikhvjs Because this is just an assumption and I haven't got the time to test it atm - hence the comment ;)

Comment: I don't use prettier

Comment: could you please explain to me what is index 0 "error" means?

Comment: You should. Especially with this kind of unusual configuration. ESlint is for linting, not formatting.

Comment: @HasiburRahman, The meaning of  `error` : https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below code to configure it

```
"indent": ["error", 4]   // Indent with 4 spaces

"react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4] // Indent JSX with 4 spaces

"react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 4]   // Indent props with 4 spaces
```

Comment: In my project I'm using Nuxt(VueJS) freamwork

Comment: Try `vue/html-indent`.